# issue with '/' while passing parameter to API

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary, nsdata, nsjsonserialization

I have the following code:-

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSData *data = [surveyAnswerForCurrentSurvey dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *answerJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSMutableDictionary *answer = [answerJson mutableCopy];

    if([answer valueForKey:question.name] != nil){
        [answer setObject:textField.text forKey:question.name];
    }
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[answer copy] options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"ns data is %@",jsonData);
    NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"json string:%@", json);
    NSDictionary *answersDict = @{@"answers_json":json};

    NSData *answersAsData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: answersDict options:0 error:nil];
    NSString *answersJSONStringify = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: answersAsData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    parameters = @{@"survey_answer":answersJSONStringify};

    [self submitSurveyAnswer];
```

the result is having three '/' which is making the parameter to be passed in API in improper format.

parameter:-

```
{ "survey_answer" = "{\"answers_json\":\"{\\\"7d2c591c-9056-405c-9509-03266842b7‌​e5\\\":[\\\"1\\\"],\‌​\\"4090442c-90ce-42c‌​2-aae8-7c812b7c0f04\‌​\\":\\\"test from postman\\\",\\\"54bdcf13-e500-418a-8bab-d0639e7e1e28\\\":\\\‌​"2\\\",\\\"63bb0722-‌​7099-4820-a400-36b89‌​38c6ae8\\\":\\\"hell‌​o\\\",\\\"f884a7d1-f‌​9d9-4563-bb6e-945386‌​64f3bd\\\":\\\"test from cms and iphone\\\",\\\"ed3acc20-4ae4-493e-ac55-4d2d0f282886\\\":\\\"‌​1\\\"}\"}"; }
```

Comment: parameter:-{
    "survey_answer" = "{\"answers_json\":\"{\\\"7d2c591c-9056-405c-9509-03266842b7e5\\\":[\\\"1\\\"],\\\"4090442c-90ce-42c2-aae8-7c812b7c0f04\\\":\\\"test from postman\\\",\\\"54bdcf13-e500-418a-8bab-d0639e7e1e28\\\":\\\"2\\\",\\\"63bb0722-7099-4820-a400-36b8938c6ae8\\\":\\\"hello\\\",\\\"f884a7d1-f9d9-4563-bb6e-94538664f3bd\\\":\\\"test from cms and iphone\\\",\\\"ed3acc20-4ae4-493e-ac55-4d2d0f282886\\\":\\\"1\\\"}\"}";
}

Comment: I added your comment to the question - which is where it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
NSDictionary *answersDict = @{@"answers_json":json};
```

Creates a JSON object with one key whose value is the string result of serialising your original JSON object. All of the `"` in the string need to be escaped with `\` so this is what it does, i.e.

```
{ "answer" : "{ "foo" : "bar" }" }
```

Is not legal because of the embedded quotes in the string. So it does this:

```
{ "answer" : "{ \"foo\" : \"bar\" }" }
```

Then you get multiplication of backslashes when you print the resulting string because the backslashes need to be escaped.

To fix the problem, use the JSON object, not its serialisation. the line above becomes:

```
NSDictionary *answersDict = @{@"answers_json": [answer copy]};
```

Comment: Thanks @jeremyP. it worked well !    NSMutableDictionary *answer = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [answer setObject:arrayOfAnswers forKey:currentQuestion.name];
    
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[answer copy] options:0 error:nil];
    NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *answersDict = @{@"answers_json":json};
    
    parameters = @{@"survey_answer":answersDict};